# Segmentation fault creating a user-level thread with C and assembly

Tags: c, assembly

I am trying to understand some OS fundamentals using some assignments. I have already posted a similar question and got satisfying answers. But this one is slightly different but I haven't been able to debug it. So here's what I do:

What I want to do is to start a main program, malloc a space, use it as a stack to start a user-level thread. My problem is with return address. Here's the code so far:

[I'm editing my code to make it up-to-date to the current state of my answer ]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define STACK_SIZE 512

void switch_thread(int*,int*);

int k = 0;

void simple_function()
{
    printf("I am the function! k is: %d\n",k);
    exit(0);
}

void create_thread(void (*function)())
{   
   int* stack = malloc(STACK_SIZE + 32);
   stack = (int* )(((long)stack & (-1 << 4)) + 0x10);
   stack = (int* ) ((long)stack + STACK_SIZE); 
   *stack = (long) function;
   switch_thread(stack,stack);  
}

int main()
{
    create_thread(simple_function);
    assert(0);
    return 0;
}
```

switch_thread is an assembly code I've written as follows:

```
.text
    .globl  switch_thread
switch_thread:  
    movq    %rdi, %rsp
    movq    %rsi, %rbp
    ret
```

This code runs really well under GDB and gives the expected output (which is,passing the control to simple_function and printing "I am the function! k is: 0". But when run separately, this gives a segmentation fault. I'm baffled by this result.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't you think that you should care about other registers on function call?

Comment: Don't forget to align your stack by 16.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen That's one point I want to clarify. Can you please explain why it should be aligned by 16?

Answer (score 7):

Two problems with your code:

1. Unless your thread is actually inside a proper procedure (or a nested procedure), there's no such thing as "base pointer". This makes the value of %rbp irrelevant since the thread is not inside a particular procedure at the point of initialization.
2. Contrary to what you think, when the `ret` instruction gets executed, the value that %rsp is referring to becomes the new value of the program counter. This means that instead of `*(base_pointer + 1)`, `*(base_pointer)` will be consulted when it gets executed. Again, the value of %rbp is irrelevant here.

Your code (with minimal modification to make it run) should look like this:

```
void switch_thread(int* stack_pointer,int* entry_point);

void create_thread(void (*function)())
{
    int* stack_pointer = malloc(STACK_SIZE + 8);
    stack_pointer += STACK_SIZE; //you'd probably want to back up the original allocated address if you intend to free it later for any reason.
    switch_thread(stack_pointer,function);      
}
```

Your switch_thread routine should look like this:

```
    .text
    .globl  switch_thread
switch_thread:
    mov     %rsp, %rax //move the original stack pointer to a scratch register
    mov     %rdi, %rsp //set stack pointer
    push    %rax       //back-up the original stack pointer
    call    %rsi       //call the function
    pop     %rsp       //restore the original stack pointer
    ret                //return to create_thread
```

FYI: If you're initializing a thread on your own, I suggest that you first create a proper trampoline that acts as a thread entry point (e.g. ntdll's RtlUserThreadStart). This will make things much cleaner especially if you want to make your program multithreaded and also pass in any parameters to the start routine.

Comment: You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc` in a C program.

Comment: Your explanation is not very clear. Can you please rephrase it? Also, what is the use of call %rsi instruction?

Comment: @user2290802 %ebp is only consulted when you're actually constructing/destroying a stack frame for a particular procedure, i.e. when you're executing `ENTER/LEAVE` instructions (or equivalent procedure prologue/epilogue). In your switch_thread function, there is no such frame (and you don't need one anyways). As for the value of %rsi register, it will hold the pointer to `simple_function()`.

Comment: Can't I store the return value as the first element in the stack and use 'ret' instead of 'call'? It works under GDB but not alone. I don't expect this function to return. It should exit without returning.

Comment: @user2290802 Yes, you can do it that way if you really want to use `ret`. In fact, your updated code in the question should work, though changing the value of %rbp still has no effect whatsoever. The reason why I used `call` in my example was because I wasn't sure whether you knew what you were doing when you were passing `base_pointer` to `switch_thread`. My intent was simply to show you the conventional way of doing it (correctly).

Answer (score 0):

`base_pointer` needs to be suitably aligned to store `void (*)()` values, otherwise you're dealing with undefined behaviour. I think you mean something like this:

```
void create_thread(void (*function)())
{
    size_t offset = STACK_SIZE + sizeof function - STACK_SIZE % sizeof function;
    char *stack_pointer = malloc(offset + sizeof *base_pointer);
    void (**base_pointer)() = stack_pointer + offset;
    *base_pointer = function;
    switch_thread(stack_pointer,base_pointer);      
}
```

There is no need to cast malloc. It's generally a bad idea to cast pointers to integer types, or function pointers to object pointer types.

I understand that this is all portable-C nit-picky advice, but it really does help to write as much as your software as possible in portable code rather than relying upon undefined behaviour.